# How to release a beta version of a crate for limited public testing?

Tags: rust, beta, rust-cargo

I want to carefully release a new version of a crate to give users a chance to test it first. How can I release it to crates.io as a "beta"? (similar to how npm has `@next` tagged releases).

It's not supposed to be a breaking change, so I'm not going to increase semver-major version. I don't want it to be automatically picked when users do `cargo upgrade` until the beta testing period ends.

- What version syntax should I use for the release?
- Do I need to use any special cargo options when releasing it?
- How do users use `cargo`/`Cargo.toml` to opt in into the beta version?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

[Semantic versioning](http://semver.org/) defines the concept of a [*pre-release version*](http://semver.org/#spec-item-9):

> A pre-release version MAY be denoted by appending a hyphen and a series of dot separated identifiers immediately following the patch version. Identifiers MUST comprise only ASCII alphanumerics and hyphen [0-9A-Za-z-]. Identifiers MUST NOT be empty. Numeric identifiers MUST NOT include leading zeroes. Pre-release versions have a lower precedence than the associated normal version. A pre-release version indicates that the version is unstable and might not satisfy the intended compatibility requirements as denoted by its associated normal version. Examples: 1.0.0-alpha, 1.0.0-alpha.1, 1.0.0-0.3.7, 1.0.0-x.7.z.92

To use this in Cargo, publish a crate of the planned version number but append a pre-release identifier. I suggest `-beta.0`, allowing you to easily increase if you need a second:

```
[package]
name = "library"
version = "0.1.1-beta.0"
```

To use this, you need to specifically opt into it by putting `beta` into the version requirement:

```
[dependencies]
library = "0.1.1-beta"
```

---

To test this, I:

1. Spun up a local crates.io server
2. Uploaded the crate *library* with version 0.1.0
3. Used `library = "0.1.0"` in a binary project *app* — it resolved to 0.1.0
4. Uploaded the crate *library* with version 0.1.1-beta.0
5. Ran `cargo update` in *app* — the version **did not** change.
6. Changed to `library = "0.1.1-beta"` in *app*, ran `cargo update` — the version **did** change.
7. Uploaded the crate *library* with version 0.1.1-beta.1
8. Ran `cargo update` in *app* — the version **did** change.

Comment: Fantastic answer. Thank you.